# Best method to handle updating Twilio capability tokens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I have a web app written in JavaScript & NodeJS that uses Twilio, when the user is online it allows incoming calls and outgoing calls. My question is; What's the best way to handle refreshing these tokens? Should I have a timer that automatically refreshes the token every X amount of minutes the user remains logged in. Is it safe to use the `Twilio.Device.offline()` callback to refresh the token? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I recommend, [as does the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device-14-beta#offline), that you do use `Twilio.Device.offline()` to listen for events where the token expires and refresh at that point. That would be more resilient than setting a timer.